# Back4app android studio how to I get all of the items in my query?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, back4app

I have been trying to pull all of the objects from a table on Back4app to populate a list in my program. I am able to add values to the table but am having trouble getting the values from the table.

How would I go about getting all the values from this table?

[The table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjkme.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you already taken a look at the official documentation about it?
http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#queries-on-array-values

Since you tagged Back4App, they have the API Reference, where you can see a sample code made based on your class.

You can see a public one (which is not be generated to your app here: https://dashboard.back4app.com/apidocs)

But, if you'd like to see one for your own app, just put your app ID in the URL below:

https://dashboard.back4app.com/apidocs/yourappidhere?java#

I hope those links can help you!